# Are there any exceptions to the rule stipulating that the article "a" be used (rather than "an") if the following word begins with a consonant?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I know that we should use "an" instead of "a" if the next word (such as a noun) is a vowel.

But I'd like to know if there is an exception to this? One example:

```
How to install an SSL certificate.
```

Is the above example incorrect or is an exception? To me, it just sounds right but I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: It’s a valid exception because *SSL* sounds like *ass ass al*, hence “a SSL” would sound bumpy. That’s a common, rough rule of thumb, but it also shows that there are just as much exceptions as rules on *a* vs. *an*.

Comment: There's a lot of variation in how people pronounce things, so there are times when either could be appropriate. For example the programming language SQL: https://oracle-base.com/blog/2015/01/02/a-sql-or-an-sql/

Answer (score 3):

If you were speaking that sentence, you'd say

> How to install an ess ess ell certificate.

The word that describes the letter S - which I represent as "ess" above - begins with a vowel sound, so "an" is appropriate.

If it's an abbreviation that's typically pronounced as a word, instead of spelling out the letters, then normal rules apply:

> They're having a NATO exercise

People pronounce NATO as "nato", not as "enn ay tee oh."

Some abbreviations are treated differently by different people. The term for a web address is "URL." I think most people spell out the letters, making it "a URL" (a you are ell), but some prefer to speak it as a word - "an URL" (an earl).

Isn't English fun?

Comment: So if the word sounds like a vowel at the beginning, we should use "an"?

Comment: Yes. you use how it sounds phonetically.

Answer (score 2):

"SSL" is an abbreviation pronounced "es-es-el."

Its first sound is a **vowel**, which is why one must use the article "**an**" rather than "a."

Comment: So if it sounds like a vowel too, we should use "an"?

Comment: If the first SOUND of an acronym or abbreviation is a vowel, absolutely.

Comment: Yes, but....  For historical reasons (chiefly that, in French, the "h" in "histoire" and "hotel" from which our words "history" and "hotel" come, is mute), it is not uncommon for "an" to precede those and similar words, as in  "An historic event", "an hotel with 45 guest rooms", even though these days we usually pronounce the "h" in both those words.  But the "h" in "hedgehog" has never been mute (except in Cockney), so we don't say "an hedgehog" (I think even a Cockney would say "a 'edgehog").